# Solving a determinant equation for the properties of a matrix $C$

Tags: matrices, determinant

Suppose I have two square $N \times N$ matrices which a satisfy
$$
\frac{\det( R + C )^2}{\det(R - (C + C^{\ast})/2) \det( R + (C + C^{\ast})/2 )} \ = \ 1
$$
where $R$ is a **real** matrix, and $C$ has entries which are **complex**-valued in general (the operation $\ast$ is just complex-conjugation here).

What can one say about the matrix $C$ from this? I can see that $C=0$ is a solution to this equation, but do there exist other solutions for $C$?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever $R$ is invertible and skewsymmetric, then $C=-2R$ is a solution